# Changing Field Labels / Data Types

Tags: fields

There are some spelling errors on a couple of fields in our opportunity layout. I would love to correct the field label. If I do this, will any data from this field get erased? Additionally, I want to change a field data type from text to currency. If I change the data type, will that erase data? Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, changing a label will not erase data.

The question on if changing the field type will erase data has some nuance to it. [Salesforce has a decent help article on this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&type=5). Converting from text to currency is likely fine (unlikely to lose data) if Salesforce allows that conversion, but I myself would not perform such an operation without first exporting all of the current data (using a tool like the [Salesforce-provided Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm))

The idea being that if something does go wrong, you can perform an update to restore previous data (auto-mapping fields should work as long as the API name isn't changing, but even if it doesn't you could manually map that field).